# LinkedIn V1 API not reliable - very slow response (over 10sec)

Tags: linkedin-api

We're using LinkedIn API for a very simple case:

- authenticate (either through SDK or web view)
- use token to fetch profile

Today we have noticed a huge degradation of service. Simple profile calls response time is in the range of 500ms - 12000ms and sometimes it returns 500.

Slow response can be easily reproduced by using the REST console from developers guide:

https://apigee.com/console/linkedin
with more than half of the requests taking more than 10sec to respond.

We also noticed tha sometimes requests return 500 from LinkedIn:

```
<-- 500  https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,first-name,last-name,email-address,formatted-name,headline,location,industry,num-connections,num-connections-capped,summary,specialties,positions,phone-numbers,public-profile-url,picture-url,picture-urls::(original))?format=json (17808ms)

{
      "errorCode": 0,
      "message": "Internal API server error",
      "requestId": "3FXP4W2HD2",
      "status": 500,
      "timestamp": 1519643223202
    }
<-- END HTTP (138-byte body)
```

This looks like a timeout on server side maybe at some point, hence failure.

Given that sometimes the API responds quickly, it does feel like one of the servers outage maybe? (I might be wrong).

Would be great to know if:

- there is a status page for the LinkedIn API that can tell us about the problems and how / when they are getting addressed.
- can we treat V1 API as reliable at all? There was a similar (but easier to workaround) problem with fetching profile just couple of weeks ago.

Comment: We are also seeing 20+ second request times for basic profile info, auth tokens, etc. and occasional 500s http://cloud.jchook.com/460Y1Y261s3V

Comment: We're also seeing failing or extremely slow requests. Also agree that there needs to be a status page for the API.

Comment: Looks like this is now resolved? With no response or explanation from LinkedIn, as usual.